# floor function and uniform distribution equivalence

Tags: statistics

suppose that U is a continuous random variable. If one knows that $\lfloor2U\rfloor\sim unif\{0,1\}$, how to show that $U\sim unif[0,1]$?

Comment: You can't show this, because it's not true.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, any distribution of $U$ that satisfies $$\Pr[0 \le U < 1/2] = \Pr[1/2 \le U < 1] = 1/2$$ will result in $\lfloor 2U \rfloor$ being discrete uniform on $\{0,1\}$.  There are infnitely many such choices, both discrete and continuous, such as:

1. $\Pr[U = 1/3] = \Pr[U = 8/9] = 1/2$.
2. $U \sim \mathrm{Beta}(a,a)$,

of which the special case $a = 1$ gives the $\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$ distribution.

Comment: what happens if $\lfloor nU\rfloor\sim unif\{0,1\}$ for $\forall n \in N$, is the conclusion true?

Comment: Clearly not:  No such $U$ could satisfy your modified criterion.  If $\Pr[U > 0] > 0$, then there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $\Pr[\lfloor nU \rfloor > 1] > 0$.  But then $\Pr[\lfloor nU \rfloor = 1] = 0$ if $U$ cannot take on any positive values.  Hence $\lfloor nU \rfloor \not\sim \mathrm{Uniform}\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample could be $U \sim \text{unif}\left[\frac12-k,\frac12+k\right]$ with $0 \lt k \lt \frac12$.